# Is it rude to ask for a Skype interview for the 2nd round of interview?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I applied for a research position at a University **abroad** and managed to go for an interview in person. The position I applied to was at Research Centre "A", but after some time, the prof emailed me suggesting that she would like to recommend me for another position at Research Centre "B" (he is the director of both centres).

He wants to arrange another interview with some of the researchers at centre "B", but honestly, I don't think I can afford making another trip down for an in-person interview, and I'm not even sure if i'll get the job. Do you think it's rude, and does it reduce my chances of making a good impression (or even getting hired), if I politely ask for a Skype interview instead?

I can't seem to find a reasonable excuse (other than expenses), so are there any other suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Expenses are a perfectly understandable reason. You should ask what other options are available.

Answer (score 2):

Expenses is a perfectly reasonable reason. If you can't afford it, then you can't afford it.

Raise the issue with them. It could be that they fund travel costs for the interview, or, as you say, they perform a Skype interview.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just *asking* for a Skype interview?
I'm assuming the professor knows that you are abroad, so it should appear as a normal demand, and definitely not rude. It happens all the time.

Your request doesn't have to mention expenses, you can point out that it would be more convenient for everyone - especially since travel time and planning would introduce a delay. Something sending the message "Thank you for your offer and I'm really excited about meeting everyone in team B, however I have no planned trip to country X any time soon, but I would be available immediately for a Skype interview" should do the trick.
If they insist on meeting in person, then you can think again about how much you want the job (or not!) and if it is worth the traveling expenses.

Then of course if you go further in the recruitement process, you will have to meet them at some point, but it can definitely wait until after the first interview.

Answer (score 0):

A job is usually required to provide "reasonable accommodation" for things like disability. They're used to sometimes having to make concessions for people. Asking for a skype interview is fine; the worst they could say is "No, we don't want you". If you're being asked for a second interview there is a safe buffer to say that they DO want you, and will likely be open to requests that make sense.

Don't delay. Ask the interviewer as soon as possible, and let them know the reasons why as simply as possible. Don't beg forgiveness or go into too much detail: "I would like to request a remote interview due to the expense of travelling at this time. I can do it any time you're comfortable doing it". The last part is important. Let them know subtly that you value their time and are willing to make concessions if they are.

Good luck on the interview!

Comment: "A job is usually required to provide "reasonable accommodation" for things like disability."  This has nothing to do with OP's question.  This has to do with things like the desk you use, or chair you sit in, etc.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Mental illness (depression) is covered for things like time off.

"Time off work may also be a reasonable accommodation. However, the ADA doesn’t require employers to give unlimited leave to someone with a disability."

(source:http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/time-off-work-reasonable-accommodation.html)

Time off, flexible work hours, etc are considered under reasonable accommodation. Otherwise, people needing time off for things like dialysis would be unable to take time off to attend.